# error defining a string

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, addition

I am trying to make a program that adds a number to a string and prints it. Here is my code:

```
n1 = 5
n2 = 6
statement = "number 1: ",n1,") (number 2: ",n2,")"
print(statement)
```

I want it to print `(number1: 5 ) * (number2:  6 )`.

**EDIT**:
The problem I had was my items were separated by commas, not plus signs. This caused an error becuase you need to seperate things with plus signs.
3 ways to get around this would be:
A:`% formatting`

```
number = 1   
statement = "Your number is %s." % (number)
```

B:`{} formatting`

```
number = 2   
statement = "Your number is {}.".format(number)
```

C:`Converting to a string`

```
number = 3   
statement = "Your number is "+str(number) + "."
```

Comment: Forgot to change title. Facepalm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to join strings using the comma operator. This creates a tuple, not a string.  Strings are concatenated using the `+` operator, like so:

```
statement = "(x +" + str(n1) + ") * (x +" + str(n2) + ")"
```

But it would be even easier to use the string formatting operators:

```
statement = "(x + {}) * (x + {})".format(n1,n2)
```

or

```
statement = "(x + %s) * (x + %s)" % (n1, n2)
```

Comment: Great, thanks! Thank you for the variety of options. In 8 min. this will be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax in line 4, where you build the statement, is one that constructs a list from comma-separated elements.  You need to convert the integers to strings somehow, and work in the spaces you want.  Here's the closest equivalent, I think:

```
statement = "(x + " + str(n1) + " ) * (x + " + str(n2) + " )"
```

This prints the output you requested.

Answer (score 0):

When you construct your "statement" variable, you are building a tuple, not a string (those commas are the culprit).

Build that variable as a string, and you'll be able to add it to the other string.

`statement = "(x + {n1}) * x +{n2})".format(n1=n1, n2=n2)`